# Get "syntax error Cannot GET /xyz" with jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I use $.ajax to request data from a node.js server. I'm debuging the client side in Firefox. I get the following error in the console: **Syntax error Cannot GET /xyz** where */xyz* is the route for my server. However, the page works properly. I would like to avoid filling the console with this error because the AJAX request is done recursively.

**Client code:**

```
startUpdateGui = function(){
    (function updateGui(){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url:        "/updategui",
                type:       "POST",
                data:       {
                                id: "master"
                            },
                timeout:    10000,
            }
        ).done( function( data ){
            $( "#time_server" ).text( data );
            updateGui();
        });
    })();
}
```

`startUpdateGui()` is called once at the end of `<body>`. Notice again that *the function performs what I want it to do*. `done()` is correctly executed.

**Server code:**

```
app.post( '/updategui', function( req, res ){
    //log.mark( 'Routing \'/updategui\' with id = "' + req.body.id + '"' );

    res.end( (new Date()).toString() );
});
```

where `app` is from `Express`.

So, looking at the client `$.ajax(...)` and the server `app.post(...)` can you see where the problem is?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jquery are you using?  Is it prior to 1.9.0?
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.  Basically if you don't set it, it's defaulted to be get.
Anyway can you update that to method?  Also you call the updateGui() inside updateGui().
I'm not sure if you want it

```
(function updateGui(){
    $.ajax(
        {
            url:        "/updategui",
            method:       "POST",  // <---- updated
            data:       {
                            id: "master"
                        },
            timeout:    10000,
        }
    ).done( function( data ){
        $( "#time_server" ).text( data );
        updateGui();  // <--- recursion 
    });
})();
```

This is my Nodejs code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()

.all('/updategui' , function(req, res, next){
    // res.write('all\n');
    next();
})

// app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
//  res.end('get\n');
// })
.post('/updategui', function(req, res, next){
    res.end('post\n');
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Hi @achan. 1) I use jQuery 1.11.3. 2) The method I want to use is "POST" but I beleived I had to set "type" rather. I found that somewhere... 3) Yes, I want the recursion.

Comment: Why are you using next() in your node.js functions()? I don't use it and it works also.

Comment: oh... i just want to test if it gets invoked at all.. (just testing). for .all, all http verbs would go through and i call next() so the post gets invoked. (chaining). i tried again with curl and it's fine...

Comment: your suggestion ("type:" -> "method:" works fine. Thank you!